# What should be the correct answer in case of use of wrong notation?

Tags: notation, logarithms

> Find the value of $$\log_{0.75}\log_2\sqrt{\sqrt[-2]{0.125}}$$

The options in my book were

> $a)$ $1$ , $b)$ undefined, $c)$ $0.5$, $d)$$\log_{\frac{3}{4}}2$

Now the book has explicitly mentioned in theory that $\sqrt[n]{a}$ is defined only for $n\geq 2$, so I blindly marked option B.

However the correct answer was option A which we get when we solve after ignoring the above rule.

What should be the correct answer in this case?

Comment: The $-2$ th root is something very unusual, but it can be viewed as $0.125^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ which is $\sqrt{8}$ which finally gives option $a)$

Comment: "... the book has explicitly mentioned in theory that $\sqrt[n]{a}$ is defined only for $n\geq 2$ ..."  If it really said this **explicitly** (rather than just failing to give other examples) then it seems like a foolish statement by the authors, who apparently don't actually believe in that restriction.

Comment: I'd say it is a crappy book that fails to play by it's own rules.  But I'd also say was we define rational and real exponents I'd automatically convert any $\sqrt[n]a = a^{\frac 1n}$ which leads to a (consistent) abuse of notation to allow $\sqrt[x]a = a^{\frac 1x}$ for any real $x$..... which is apparently what the book is doing  **against its** ***own*** **rules**.